# While loop not accepting the break function, classed as syntax error?

Tags: python

Am in the middle of a project for school and am trying to use a while True loop in order to get a specific answer from an input. I tried the following and IDLE labels break as a syntax error.

```
while True:
    RequestTea = input("What tea would you like? English Breakfast, Green Tea or Earl Grey? ").lower()
if RequestTea.lower() not in ('earl grey','english breakfast','green tea'):
    print("Not an appropriate choice.")
else:
    break
```

Can anyone please help? I don't see why it's not accepting the loop function.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Because your `if` statement isn't part of your loop.

Comment: Probably an indentation problem. Also not a good idea to capitalize variable names like that; reserve that form for class names.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will try to use lowercase variable names from now. @JimStewart

Comment: On that point, [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the canonical style guide for Python code.

Comment: Indent the if-else statement inside the while loop.

Comment: Thank you all fixed now. @MorganThrapp

Comment: @JayRosenthal, to mark the question resolved, click the checkbox by the answer that solved your problem. Until that's done (or the question is otherwise marked closed), it's still shown as lacking an accepted answer.

Comment: Can't accept it for '6 minutes' @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    RequestTea = input("What tea would you like? English Breakfast, Green Tea or Earl Grey? ").lower()
    if RequestTea.lower() not in ('earl grey','english breakfast','green tea'):
        print("Not an appropriate choice.")
    else:
        break
```

Indent blocks

Comment: Thank you very much. My mistake.@blue-monday

Comment: Typo questions should be closed, not answered.

Comment: I understand the problem - will look more closely in future.